# how to get address of humidity and temperatuer sensor?

Tags: modbus, modbus-tcp

I have forgotten the address of temperature and humidity sensor.
How can I retrieve the address of sensor??
Hint I use model(JXBS-3001-TR-RS)

Comment: This looks like a duplicate of [your issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68557732/how-to-change-the-address-of-npk-sensor-throughthe-code) that was closed yesterday. The reason your question was closed was clearly stated;  if you edit the question and add sufficient information then it may be reopened.

Comment: no,not the same question. in this question i forget the address of the sensor and i want  talk to that sensor but i don't know how because  i forget his address. so i ask how to reset the sensor to make return to his default address?

Comment: I added a link to the manual for this device in the comments on your other question. Unfortunately it makes no mention of a factory reset function nor does it provide information on how settings are stored. I'd suggest trying the 'Auto Find Device' option in the software (if not the manufacturer provides a range of contact options).